# when video play the whole webview is overlapping the bottom of the adview in android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-video-player

I have a webview in my project and i am successfully load url in webview.In my website which i am loading in webview there are video list.So i am successfully playing the video.But when videolist is showing the entire webview is overlapping the bottom of the admob adview.My layout is perfect for other screen.But only overlapping in videoscreen.here is my code:

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);



        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/amazon");
```

How can i fix this? please help.